# AngualrJs ngGrid make column mandatory

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to have make some columns mandatory in the ngGrid.
Is there a way to get the required attribute in a cell.

thanks

Comment: This is a very compact question that leads to a lot of meta questions. What do you mean? Editing?

Comment: something along the lines of <input type="text" required/> so that the user is aware that he/she has to fill in the data for that column